# How to MagicMock a list of object with method and get assert count

Tags: python, python-unittest, magicmock

I am new to unit testing in python with MagicMock. I have the following code to assert the correct method count in python:

```
 def methodFoo(self):
       for booObject in self.booObjectList:
            booObject.shooMethod()
```

I wish to perform an assertion call count of the method `shooMethod()` in my unit test code to see if for N objects in `booObjectList` it performs N calls. The above function is not my unit test code. It is a method to be tested by creating a new method `test_methodFoo()` in my unit test class. How do I go about it? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mock` objects have an attribute [`called`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.called) that tracks whether a Mock has been called, and an attribute [`call_count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_count) that tracks how many times they were called.

```
def test_methodFoo(self):
    self.object_under_test.methodFoo()
    self.assertTrue(all([booObject.shooMethod.called for
                         booObject in self.object_under_test.booObjectList]))
```

Note however that you can't do something like:

```
for o in list_of_four_o_mocks:
    o.mocked_method()
self.assertEqual(o.mocked_method.call_count, 4)
```

since `o` is a new object each time.

Comment: Hi Adam thanks for your reply. I wish to point out that this is the method which I have to test. I'll be having a separate unit-test method isolated which will test the above method. Apologies, maybe my post wasn't clear.

Comment: @harsh8888 is my edit more in line with what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

As Adam Smith has already answered your question, just a personal advice - I too faced lot of issues working with mock library when I started doing mocking. Besides python-mock does not works for other teating clients like pytest etc. So I recommend you to use fudge library. It is more pythonic and works with all testing clients.

Comment: yes I found a few issues working with mock. Thank you for your advice. I'll look into fudge!